# Setting one variable equal to another in C

Tags: c, variables, global-variables

I am writing a code in C. It is in an environment with precoded functions, so I can't explain it completely. I wanted to iterate over a variable but this wasn't working. I eventually figured out this was because the variable was not defined globally but in a function, and was being redefined every time the function was called.

Now, at the top of my code, globally, I want to write the following code.

```
int killing_time = 20000;
int killing_period;
killing_period = killing_time;
```

The compiler gives me the following errors:

`data definition has no type or storage class`

Don't I clearly define it to be an integer?

`initializer element is not constant`

If I define `killing_time` as `const int killing_time = 20000` it still gives the same error:

`type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘killing_period'`

I could of course define `killing_period` to be `20000` and just start iterating over that, but I want to know what is going on.

I hope we can figure this out  together.

Comment: `int killing_period = killing_time;` should work fine (if my memory serves me well). You can't really execute arbitrary statements in global scope like that.

Comment: You cant do these kind of assignment in global scope I think only initializations.

Comment: Using global variables is likely not the right (or at least best) way to do things. But can't give any more specific info without more context.

Comment: `#define KILLING_TIME_DEFAULT 20000`

Comment: You cannot execute a statement outside of a function.

Comment: @byxor Nope, your memory doesn't serve you well :) Can't do assignment of non-constant expressions at file scope either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`killing_period = killing_time;` is executable code and you simply can't have executable code outside functions.

Nor can you do this:

```
int killing_time = 20000;
int killing_period = killing_time; // wrong
```

Because these are file scope variables and therefore have *static storage duration*. And variables with static storage duration can only be initialized by what C calls a constant expression. `20000` above is an integer constant expression, but `killing_time` isn't.

The simple fix is to do something like this instead:

```
#define KILLING_TIME 20000
...
int killing_time = KILLING_TIME;
int killing_period = KILLING_TIME;
```

Comment: This does seem like the most straightforward solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`killing_period = killing_time;` is not a valid statement in the global scope.

You can use assignment on declaration, but assigned variable (initializer element) must be constant:

```
const int killing_time = 20000;
int killing_period = killing_time;
```

Anyway, you shouldn't do it like that.

There's more than one way to do this, one of them is to pass the address of your iterator to the function where you use it, that way the changes made in the scope of the function are permanent:

```
void f1(int* i){
    (*i)++;    //will increment i
}

void f2(int* i){
    (*i)++;    //will increment i
}

int main ()
{
    int i = 0;
    f1(&i);          //pass the address of i
    f2(&i);          //pass the address of i
    printf("%d", i); // i = 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you know... just type `i++;` instead of calling a function...

Comment: @Lundin, the issue, as I understand it, is that the OP is using an iterator inside the scope of a function, and naturally it gets reseted as it is called, this is one possible solution.

Comment: No, that's just their explanation why they ended up with global variables to begin with.

Comment: @Lundin, yes you're right, but I figured that offering a different solution to the problem could be a good adition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is an interesting solution. I have been working in a particular environment of C and so I may have missed some of the basics. I will brush up.

Answer (score 0):

`killing_period = killing_time;` is your problem. It is an executable statement and not allowed in global space... it must be within a function.

Still not sure what you are after, but would the following help?

```
int killing_time = 20000;
int killing_period = -1;     // negative if not yet set

int your_function(void)
{
    if ( killing_period < 0 ) {
         /* one-time initialization on the first call */
         killing_period = killing_time;
    }

    return killing_period;
}
```

If you need multiple functions setting killing_period it may be be best to burry that in a separate function dedicated to the test and set, or perhaps a macro.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert for your reply.